# How to power two stacked motor shields with one 3S Lipo battery (11.1V)?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, motor, arduino-motor-shield, battery

I have these 2 motor shields:
**Adafruit Motor Shield V2** and 
**Seed Motor Shield V2**.

They are stacked on top of an **Arduino UNO**.

My question is, how can I power 2 of those motor shields with one 3S Lipo battery(**Turnigy 3S 2200mAh 20C**), given that I have 6 identical 4.6-6V DC gearmotors?

Thanks!

Comment: Get a UBEC (switching buck regulator) for 5V with enough current to drive the motors. Turnigy do some good ones.

Comment: Could you provide links to the gear you are using?

Comment: Buck regulator as Majenko says is best with battery you have. BUT better is probably a 2S LiIon and linear regulator - only if you are willing to change battery.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Why linear? Isn't that wasteful of energy? A buck regulator will increase the current availability from the batteries, but a linear won't. 6 motors could be quite thirsty on current, especially stall current...

Comment: @Majenko Note that I suggested linear only with 2S LiIon. 2S range is say 6V - 8.4V with most energy in say 6.4-8V range or maybe 7.8V. AT 8V to 6V linear regulator gives 75% efficiency. At mid range of say (8+6.4)/2 = 7.1V efficiency at 6V out is 6/7.1 = 85%. Buck is better than that across range but if you want usefully high stall currents then a linear reg that handles 1 or 2 or 4 A is a doddle. Buck is not overly hard but harder. Simplicity wise linear is nice. Losses per amp are 2W at 8V and 0.4W at 6.4V. IF gearmotors allow slightly >6V they may allow 2S directly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Note that I recommended a UBEC specifically - that is a single module with battery input and 5V output. Not a single component or a circuit you have to build. They are designed for model vehicle enthusiasts, and I even recommended one by the same manufacturer as the battery (I use the same make myself as it happens). No messing with components or circuitry, just wire it up and away you go. You can't get simpler than that - even simpler than wiring your own linear with all that messing with capacitors ;)

Comment: @sa_leinad Sure: https://www.amazon.com/Seeed-motor-shield-for-Arduino/dp/B00KAE2B3U/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1475012972&sr=8-1&keywords=seeed+motor+shield https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00PUTH3B0/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0072AEY5I/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @Majenko Thank you so much! So if I want to power those two motor shields at the same time, I would need two UBECs?

Comment: It depends on the current capacity of the UBEC and the current requirements of the motors. If one UBEC can provide enough current then you can power both shields off one UBEC - just connect the output of the UBEC to both shields.

Comment: @Majenko  there are 6 identical motors (each takes max 250mA and min 190mA). First motor shield will control 2 motors (or 500mA) and second one will control 4 motors (or 1A). Would [this 3A](https://www.amazon.com/Ship-Hobbywing-Switch-mode-UBEC-Lowest/dp/B008ZNWOYY/ref=sr_1_1?s=toys-and-games&rps=1&ie=UTF8&qid=1475014084&sr=1-1&keywords=UBEC&refinements=p_85%3A2470955011)  UBEC do the job? Thank you again!

Comment: Yep, that would do it fine - and still leave you plenty of capacity to also power the Arduino as well if you like.

Comment: @Majenko Sweet, I ordered it. I will post the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using a linear voltage regulator. Try using [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JUFJ1GA) voltage regulator.

You will get 5 Volts 2 Amp output which should be easy to connect to motor shield's input power ports.

Comment: Thanks. How is this different from UBEC suggested by @Majenko ?

Comment: No, you really don't want to run a motor on a regulator.  Choose an appropriate power source, use a regulator *for the electronics* and use PWM to deliver an appropriate amount of power to the motors.